# Is it possible to collect Apple Health/Google Fit data when app is backgrounded or killed?

Tags: android, ios, healthkit, google-fit

We have an app where challenges are implemented (Get 5k steps, etc.) that gets data from Apple Health/Google Fit. Is it possible for the app to collect health data even when backgrounded or killed, and possibly send out API calls also when the challenges are reached?

Note: I've seen Fitness.RecordingApi for Google Fit, but as mentioned above could we send out an API call whenever the app receives data even when backgrounded or killed?

Comment: Hi Lawrence, welcome to SO. I would suggest asking two different questions, as the approaches might be different between iOS and Android and two different discussions might arise. For iOS though, try looking into HKObserverQuery (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkobserverquery).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.